# Long polling Jquery in JAVA?

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, long-polling

This is the question for my `Java Chat application` .

I will call the `pingAction()` in my external Jquery when my application get initiated.

The `Jquery pingAction` will be ,

```
function pingAction(){

    $.ajax(
            {
                type: "post",
                url: "PingAction",
                async:     false,
                data : "userId="+encodeURIComponent(userId)+"&secureKey="+encodeURIComponent(secureKey)+"&sid="+Math.random() ,
                cache:false,
                complete: pingAction,
                timeout: 5000 ,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
                dataType: "html",

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("xhr.status : "+xhr.status);

                if(xhr.status == 12029 || xhr.status == 0){
                    //alert("XMLHttp status : "+xhr.status);
                    $("#serverMsg").css("backgroundColor" , "yellow");
                    $("#serverMsg").text("Your Network connection is failed !");
                    $("#serverMsg").show();
                }
                //setTimeout('pingAction()', 5000);
                xhr.abort();
            },

            success: function( responseData , status){
                if($("#serverMsg").text() == "" || $("#serverMsg").text() == "Your Network connection is failed !"){
                    disableServerMessage();
                }

                if(responseData != "null" && responseData.length != 0  && responseData != null){

                    var stringToArray = new Array;
                    stringToArray = responseData.split("<//br//>");
                    var len = stringToArray.length;
                    for(var i=0;i<len-1;i++){
                        getText(stringToArray[i]);

                    }
                }

                //setTimeout('pingAction()', 5000);
            } 

            }                           
    );

}
```

My `PingAction Servlet` will be ,

```
public class PingAction extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String secureKey;
    private String userId;
    private int fromPosition ;
    private FlexChatProtocol protocol = null;
    private Ping ping = null;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        secureKey = request.getParameter("secureKey");
        userId = request.getParameter("userId");
        CustomerInfo customer = ApplicationInfo.customerDetails.get(userId);
        if(customer != null){
            fromPosition = customer.getFromPosition();
        }

        if(ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol != null ){

            protocol = ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol;

            ping = new Ping();
            ping.sendPing(secureKey, userId, fromPosition+1, protocol, serverMessage);

            if(customer != null){
            message = customer.getFullMessage();
            }

            out.println(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Before using the `Long Poling` , I will call the `pingAction() in javaScript` for every `5 seconds` using the `setTimeInterval()` to refresh the connection and getting the server message.

Now I need to use the `LONG POLLING concept` in the Chat application.So I modified my `Jquery pinAction()` what you have seeing above.

How can I achieve `LONG POLLING` using the `JQUERY`?

Hope our stack members will help me !

Comment: Is there any way to do long polling only with JQUERY ?

Answer (score 1):

```
private ChatContext context = ChatContext.getInstance();

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Long lastmessage = // just put this somewhere

    List<String> messages = context.getMessagesIHaventGotYet(lastmessage); // blocking call
    Object formatedMessages = formatmessages(messages);
    out.write(formatedMessages);

 }
```

context.getMessagesIHaventGotYet(); should be a blocking operation so it keeps on waiting untill new messages arrive, then it kicks into action.
or something along those lines.

Basicly long polling means the server "hangs" untill the information it needs has been retrieved from somewhere, then it writes it in its output buffer and closes the connection, the client instantiates the conneciton ASAP again to start another long poll.

Comment: Is there any way to do long polling only with `JQUERY` ?

Comment: just poll like you regularly would, except you don't poll on an interval but as soon you get a reply from the server, just start a long-poll again. A long poll should be looked at like a blocking queue's take function, if there is something in there you'll get it. and right after you got whatever it was you usualy just handle what you retrieved from the queue, and call the take command again. It's the back-end making the connection hang untill there is info, so no if the back-end just returns nothing when there is nothing you can't use jquerry to make it do so...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any `builtin` method in `Jquery` to do `long polling`  ?

Comment: jquery doesn't care whether a connection to the server will be short-lived or long-lived. you can just use $.ajax and the likes. You just need to make sure the connection doesn't time-out. A long polling call is just any call stuck in the server till it has the data it needs to respond. The key is making your server hang in a non bussy-waiting way, and making sure the connections don't time out.

Comment: @G-Man What's the best way to have a blocking operation, is an infinite loop with a condition t break it a clean way ?

Comment: no, bussy waiting or spinlocking (what you are suggesting) puts unneeded load on the cpu. you want to use the same technique as long polling. An easy way to do this would be having a blockingqueue of notifications for each conected user, let the user's thread call take() on the queue, when a different thread puts an item in the queue, the thread will wake-up, another method is using object.wait() and object.notify() methods.