# Long polling with AJAX and Spring works unstable

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, long-polling

I have a web page which polls data from server with long polling. My javascript code is:

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "graph.htm",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        timeout: 30000,

        success: successFunc,

        complete: getData

    });
}

function successFunc(data, textStatus){
    console.log(data);
    //......
}
```

and I have a Controller on server,which checks every second, if database is modified and if it is - it sends the data:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/graph", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void graphPOST(HttpServletResponse response) {
    while(!daoService.isModified()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
      String jsonData = daoService.getJsonData();

      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      response.getWriter().write(jsonData);

      System.out.println("=== sent!");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}
```

And usually it works fine. **BUT** sometimes (maybe, one time from ten) i have the situation:

1. Data is sent from server (I see the meessage "=== sent!" in console).
2. Client gets nothing (javasrcipt console is clear, there are no messages from console.log()).

Comment: It looks like u have an infinite loop. Complete will call itself again (getData) and you do not have a fail method to handle if server side throws an exception.

Comment: Churk, can infinite loop be the reason of unstable behaviour of my application?

Comment: Infinite loop, if unintended, can be a system killer for any application. Your application seems like it takes the flow of. Ajax Call, if success call success function and then loop back and run again. If ajax failed, it will exit without any logging or error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long polling Jquery in JAVA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363241/long-polling-jquery-in-java)